# Best way to earn Simoleons in SimCity Social?

Tags: simcity-social

As a long time SimCity 4 player, I am playing SimCity Social so as to wait for SimCity 5.
The game is not as casual as I thought a Facebook game would be, and my growth is kind of stagnant, having more land permits than Simoleons to expand.
So, I am looking for some verdicts on the various ways of earning Simoleons.

- Cheap, frequent pay out business
- Expensive, infrequent pay out business
- Farm
- Selling materials
- Selling fame bought buildings

(Is that all?)

I know it also depends on your pattern of available time. What are some generic ways to factor that in?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what you mentioned,

- Clicking on the mayor's house typically gives you several thousand §. (Every 24 h. [Value depends on house level](http://simcitysocial.wikia.com/wiki/Mayor's_House).)
- Building a university and sending your citizens to work gives you "salary".
- The game's [Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/simcitysocial) gives out freebies every day, sometimes a significant amount of Simoleons.
- Bonus when you level up.

Most businesses have short cycles but returns only small amounts, as you've mentioned. I believe most players do not sit in front of their PCs all day, but play it once or twice a day. In that case, it's a better idea to gain from 24-hour cycle tasks: mayor's house, farms (soybeans and wool), and sending citizens to work (give them a 24-hour job).